# Shortest Remaining Time Scheduling

Tags: cpu, scheduling, srt

Can the results of a Shortest Remaining Time Schedule be the same preemptive and non preemptive? Like, can you still get the same times at the end of both or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not impossible.It depends on the arrival time and burst time of the processes.

For example:If we have processes with following arrival time and burst times.

P1  1,2

P2  2,4

P3  3,5

It gives the same result,be it preemptive or non preemptive.